# Read text as UTF-8 encoding

Tags: r, utf-8, locale

Suppose I write a function that parses an input stream containing German. Below a toy example. The following works on my machine (because UTF8 is standard):

```
readLines(textConnection("Zürich"))
readLines(textConnection("Z\u00FCrich")) #same thing
```

However I want to make sure it works also when `UTF-8` is not the current locale encoding. For example inside rApache, default is `ascii`. Hence I pass the encoding parameter:

```
readLines(textConnection("Zürich", encoding="UTF-8"))
readLines(textConnection("Z\u00FCrich", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

But this actually results in output getting messed up. Why is this? How should I call `textConnection` to make sure the stream gets read properly on any platform or locale?

Comment: Have you tried `readLines(textConnection("Z\u00FCrich", encoding="UTF-8"), encoding="UTF-8")` ?

Comment: That seems to work. Could you elaborate in an answer why this works?

Comment: You can also try `enc2utf8` or `iconv` something like `readLines(textConnection(enc2ut8("Z\u00FCrich"), encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: ...but I have no idea, was just a good guess.

Comment: @Jeroen read the help for the encoding argument of `readLines` carefully - it's basically useless.

Answer (score 7):

The suggestion by @flodel did the trick indeed:

```
readLines(textConnection("Z\u00FCrich", encoding="UTF-8"), encoding="UTF-8")
```

However it never became clear to me why this is needed.