# Remove Crazy Characters in R/Shiny

Tags: regex, r, special-characters, shiny, shiny-server

I have a long list in the format like such:

```
group1 Â» group2 Â» group3
```

Within R, I can use a `gsub('Â»', '-', x)` where `x` is the vector structured like above.

However, I am running into errors when trying to utilize this functionality when loading this into a shiny app.  I've tried multiple ways to use `gsub`, `chartr`, and some other ones.

Also, The `Â` character is not captured when using `[[:punct:]]`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what characters do you want to *keep*, alphanumeric?

Comment: There are times where colons and semi-colons are used.  So, alpha-numeric plus a few special characters

Comment: Have you tried `gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "-", x)` ?

Comment: try `iconv(x, to='ASCII', sub='')`

Comment: "the ‘i’ stands for ‘internationalization’." thanks r core

Comment: The `iconv` function seems to be doing the trick!  I've never come across that one before, so thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group1 Â» group2 Â» group3` is a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded string and therefore it would be best if the **R** application is coded to read the strings with conversion from UTF-8 to Latin 1 as explained on [Read or Set the Declared Encodings for a Character Vector](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html) and [Read text as UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512834/).

`Â»` is the UTF-8 encoded [right-pointing double angle quotation mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet) whereby the 2 bytes with the hexadecimal values C2 BB are interpreted and displayed (wrong) with code page [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (Latin-1).

`gsub("\\xC2?\\xBB", "-", x)` could be used to find in a UTF-8 encoded string or single byte encoded string (Latin 1 or Windows 1252) all right pointing guillemets and replace each of them by a hyphen character.